# Multiple side-by-side signatures in letter

Tags: scrlttr2

I am attemting to add three side-by-side signature to a `scrlttr2` letter by using a `minipage` environment in the signature definition. I am getting an error: `Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup` pointing me to the closing line. The error goes away if i do without the minpages. Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[%
paper=letter,
pagesize,
fontsize=10pt,
standard
]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Sender's Name}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Some street\\in some town\\with zip code}
\begin{filecontents}{standard.lco}
    \setkomavar{signature}{% 
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.33\linewidth}
    First name\\
    Position 1
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.33\linewidth}
    Second name\\
    Position 2
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.33\linewidth}
    Third name\\
    Position 3
    \end{minipage}
}

\@setplength[1]{sigindent}{0.01\textwidth}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{%
Recipient's name,\\
Some position\\
More address info
}

\opening{Dear Recipient}
\lipsum[1-2]

\closing{Sincerely,}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

The document renders correctly, even though the compilation fails. Am I going the right way about this?

Comment: can you post the error message you get when you try to compile it?

Comment: Sure thing:

`ERROR: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.

---TeX said ---
<recently read> }
l.153  \closing{Sincerely,}

--- HELP ---
From the .log file...

I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be spurious, as in '$x}$'. but perhaps the } is legitimate and you forgot something else, as in \hbox{$x}'. In such cases the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the deleted material, e.g. by typing `I$}'`

Comment: It also says 'TeX has become confused. The position indicated by the error locator is probably beyond the point where the incorrect input is.` For what is worth, I've checked all my braces and they are balanced. There's no math in this document. The error goes away when I remove the minipages.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of `minipage`s you can use `\parbox`es:

```
\documentclass[%
paper=letter,
pagesize,
fontsize=10pt,
standard
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\Sigline[4][t]{%
  \parbox[#1]{.333\linewidth}{\raggedright#2}%
  \parbox[#1]{.333\linewidth}{\raggedright#3}%
  \parbox[#1]{.333\linewidth}{\raggedright#4}%
}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Sender's Name}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Some street\\in some town\\with zip code}
\setkomavar{signature}{% 
   \Sigline{First name}{Second name}{Third name} \\
  \Sigline{Position 1}{Position 2}{Position 3} \\
}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{%
Recipient's name,\\
Some position\\
More address info
}

\opening{Dear Recipient}
\lipsum[2]

\closing{Sincerely,}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think it's critical to mention that you used `\textwidth` instead of `\linewidth`. Not sure, since I didn't delve deep enough...

Comment: @Werner Hmmm I was just editiong to change to `\linewidth`; can you elaborate your comment, please?

Comment: This worked! Why should I prefer `parbox` over `minipage` in this case, and why did you replace `\textwidth`for `\linewidth`?

Comment: @Ricardo `\textwidth` produced overfull boxes; as for the reason `\parbox` works but `minipage` doesn't, I am not so sure in this case and will have to look more closely to what `\setkomavar` and `signature` do.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: When I used `\linewidth` instead of `\textwidth`, it seemed like the signature was squished horizontally. I thought it might be that it puts it in a reduced-width box.

Comment: Some elaboration on what the `\sigline` function is doing would be helpful.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a solution that is independent of any particular document class.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore
et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.

\def\s#1#2{\vbox{\hsize=4.5cm
    \kern2cm
    \hrule\kern1ex
    \hbox to \hsize{\strut\hfil #1 \hfil}
    \hbox to \hsize{\strut\hfil #2 \hfil}}}

\hbox to \hsize{\s{John Doe}{President}\hfil
    \s{Jane Doe}{COO}\hfil
    \s{James Dow}{CFO}} 

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]