# Two signature wilcards side by side

Tags: formatting, vertical-alignment, positioning

> <sub>I'm quite sure someone already has asked this question before. However, I can't find an answer to my question so I thought I'd ask you guys.</sub>

As the title says, I'd like to have two signature lines next to each other with 2 names below them. So far I've written this code:

```
\begin{center}
    \hbox{
        \vbox{------------------------------------------------  \\ Name 1} \hspace*{2cm} 
        \vbox{------------------------------------------------  \\ Name 2}
         }
\end{center}
```

However it seems like the first `\vbox` is swallowing the other one and it visually looks like this (I know, nothing special to see here I guess): [image: Figure 1: vbox swallowing other one]

Any idea how I could solve this problem (two `\vbox`es in one `\hbox`, or maybe another solution with two `\vbox`es)?

Comment: Here are more options/ideas: [Multiple side-by-side signatures in letter](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67622/5764); [Multiple signatures in a letter](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2126/5764); [Dynamic signature/date line](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48152/5764)

Answer (score 6):

No need for `\vbox` really. You can define your wildcard as a `\parbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*\wildcard[2][5cm]{\vspace*{2cm}\parbox{#1}{\hrulefill\par#2}}

\begin{document}
Some text...

\begingroup
  \centering
  \wildcard{Name 1}
  \hspace{1cm}
  \wildcard{Name 2}
  \par
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

*Note*. If you want to have the text under the wildcard centered you can define your wildcard macro as

```
\newcommand*\wildcard[2][5cm]{\vspace*{2cm}\parbox{#1}{\centering\hrulefill\par#2\par}}
```

### Addendum

If you are really bound to the `\vbox` primitive the above definition could be translated to:

```
\newcommand*\wildcard[2][5cm]{%
  \mbox{%
    \vbox to 3cm{%
      \vfill
      \hbox to #1{\hrulefill}\par
      \hbox to #1{\strut\hfil#2\hfil}
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
```

Why not use a `tabular` with 2 columns? Or with 3 columns where the middle column is empty to get some extra space. Use `\cline` for the horizontal line.

```
\begin{document}
Some previous text
\vspace{3cm}

\begin{tabular}{p{0.45\textwidth}cp{0.45\textwidth}}
  \cline{1-1} \cline{3-3} \\
  \centering Name1 & & \centering Name2 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]